# How to update/reset a Pact interaction during development?

Tags: c#, .net, pact

I run into this issue regularly with [PactNet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PactNet/) during development, running locally on Windows, and I'm not sure if there's a beter way to deal with it.

Here's my scenario...

- I write a new unit test that sets up a Pact with a sample request and the body that should be returned

```
Contract.MockProviderService
    .UponReceiving("...example description...")
    .Given("...example state...")
    .With(ProviderServiceFactory.Request(HttpVerb.Get, "/endpoint"))
    .WillRespondWith(ProviderServiceFactory.Response(200, new {
        some_value = 22
    }));
```

- I run my test at least once. Maybe is passes, maybe it fails.
- I decide to make a change to the body that is returned. Maybe I've discovered a mistake or I changed my mind about the sample data I want it to return.

```
Contract.MockProviderService
    .UponReceiving("...example description...")
    .Given("...example state...")
    .With(ProviderServiceFactory.Request(HttpVerb.Get, "/endpoint"))
    .WillRespondWith(ProviderServiceFactory.Response(200, new {
        some_value = 123
    }));
```

- I try to run my test again, and Pact comes back with an error complaining that I've already defined this interaction with a different body:

> An interaction with same description ("...example description...") and
> provider state ("...example state...") but a different response body
> has already been used. Please use a different description or provider
> state, or remove any random data in the interaction.

Yes... I know, I wanted to change the body but keep the Description and Provider State the same.

It seems all I can do is make some arbitrary change to my Description and/or Provider State before I can run my test again. Either that or I have to reboot my machine to get the Pact server back to a clean state.

Is there an easier way to tell the Pact server to just wipe away and reset all of it's previously-defined interactions? Maybe something I can just call at the beginning of a unit test session?

Just looking around the available methods, I've tried `MockProviderService.ClearInteractions()` and `MockProviderService.Stop(); MockProviderService.Start();` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Pact .NET are you using? If using the 4.x.x or later, you need to clear out the pact files because it always merges interactions into the pact file and won't overwrite interactions by default.

I think you are using a previous version though, based on the questions.

Have you tried clearing out the pact file in advance? Are you specifying a write mode or using the default (overwrite)?

> Either that or I have to reboot my machine to get the Pact server back to a clean state.

This is definitely not expected, and tells me that the Pact Mock server is *not* properly shutting down between test runs.

Have you tried upgrading to the latest? All of these additional lifecycle methods aren't required in 4.x.x and should simplify a lot of the setup.

Comment: I'll have to check this out... I think the issue is that our projects only reference the `PactNet.Windows` nuget package. It's latest version is 3.0.2, and its dependency is on `PactNet (>= 3.0.2)`. So it implicitly only uses PactNet 3.0.2. I'll try explicitly adding PactNet 4.4.0 and see if things improve.